# PostgreSQL - Remover tupla referenciada por outra tabela

Tags: postgresql, query, chave-estrangeira, delete

Estou com um problema que não encontrei nada no Google (talvez eu não soube perguntar à ele)

**Imaginem o seguinte:**

- Tenho 11 tabelas, uma chamada *tbl_pai* e outras 10 chamadas *tbl_filha1*, *tbl_filha2*, *tbl_filha{n}*.
- Nas tabelas filhas possui um campo chamado *id_pai* e uma constraint (*CONSTRAINT fk_filha_com_pai FOREIGN KEY (id_pai) REFERENCES tbl_pai(id)*)

**Ou seja, 10 tabelas que possuem chaves estrangeiras referenciadas para a tabela principal**

**A dúvida é:** Como posso testar de modo elegante para saber se posso ou não remover uma tupla da tabela principal? Só consegui pensar em duas opções: Tentar excluir o registro da 'pai' e tratar o erro caso o registro esteja referenciado em outra tabela, ou, fazer um *COUNT* em todas as tabelas filhas para saber se há dependência.

Eu preciso dessa informação para decidir se disponibilizo ou não um botão de *DELETE* na minha aplicação. Se o registro não possuir referência, eu exibo o botão, se não eu oculto o botão. O problema é que esse botão fica em uma listagem (de registros da 'pai') e essa verificação precisa ser feita para cada registro. Eu fiz usando o *COUNT* mas ficou extremamente lento visto que a tabela 'pai' possui mais de um milhão de registros.

Existe um método menos custoso?

Obrigado pessoal.

Comment: como você fez o seu count?? poste a Query que você havia feito

Comment: Tudo bem mas preciso deixar de usar o count. No exemplo acima eu falei de tabelas imaginárias, a query que vou postar é a real:

Comment: `SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(t.id) FROM telemetria t WHERE t.id_sistema = s.id) +
    (SELECT COUNT(a.id) FROM alerta a WHERE a.id_sistema = s.id) +  
    (SELECT COUNT(c.id) FROM controle c WHERE c.id_sistema = s.id) + 
    (SELECT COUNT(cs.id) FROM cliente_sistema cs WHERE s.id_sistema = s.id) AS qtde 
    FROM sistema s 
    WHERE s.id = 1;`

A tabela 'telemetria' é muito volumosa. A listagem na aplicação é de sistemas e preciso verificar se disponibilizo ou não o botão para excluir o sistema.

Comment: Gustavo de uma olhada nessa pergunta:
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23041/is-there-a-way-to-test-whether-delete-will-fail-due-to-constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monteu uma função para isso :

```
CREATE LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION checkDependence(VARCHAR, VARCHAR, INTEGER) RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
DECLARE 
    tableName   ALIAS FOR $1;
    columnName  ALIAS FOR $2;
    id          ALIAS FOR $3;

    sqlExecute  RECORD;
    sqlExecute2 RECORD;
    sqlQuery    VARCHAR;
    sqlQuery2   VARCHAR;
    primaryKey  VARCHAR;
BEGIN

    sqlQuery := 'SELECT table_name';
    sqlQuery := sqlQuery || ' FROM information_schema.columns';
    sqlQuery := sqlQuery || ' WHERE table_name != '''||tableName||'''';
    sqlQuery := sqlQuery || ' AND column_name = '''||columnName||'''';

    FOR sqlExecute IN EXECUTE(sqlQuery) LOOP

        RAISE NOTICE '%', sqlExecute.table_name;
        RAISE NOTICE '%', columnName;
        RAISE NOTICE '%', id;

        sqlQuery2 := 'SELECT CASE WHEN count(1) > 0 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS has';
        sqlQuery2 := sqlQuery2 || ' FROM '||sqlExecute.table_name;
        sqlQuery2 := sqlQuery2 || ' WHERE '||columnName||' = '||id;

        FOR sqlExecute2 IN EXECUTE(sqlQuery2) LOOP
            RAISE NOTICE '%', sqlExecute2;
            IF sqlExecute2.has THEN
                RETURN TRUE;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN FALSE;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Agora so sera necessário chamá-la no seu select :

```
SELECT
    checkDependence('table_pai', 'id', id);
```

Comment: Cara, perfeito! Funcionou maravilhosamente bem e o raciocínio ficou muito inteligente. A query levou 180ms na minha base de dados. Obrigado pela contribuição, dessa forma ficou extremamente modular sendo possível usar para qualquer tabela desde que siga o padrão correto de dar sempre o mesmo nome para as chaves estrangeiras da tabela, como no meu caso. Ótimo, parabéns! Abraços!

Comment: De nada @Gustavo, que bom que ajudou :D

Answer (score 1):

Fazer `count` pode ser lento. Solução com o `exists`:

```
select *,
    not (
        exists (
            select 1
            from telemetria
            where id_sistema = s.id
        ) or
        exists (
            select 1
            from alerta
            where id_sistema = s.id
        ) or
        exists (
            select 1
            from controle
            where id_sistema = s.id
        ) or
        exists (
            select 1
            from cliente_sistema
            where id_sistema = s.id
        )
    ) as pode_deletar
from sistema s
```

Se ficar com bom desempenho pode também ser transformado em função

Answer (score 0):

Se as linhas das tabelas filhas que você está verificando não forem importantes, digo, se você precisa apenas consultar a existência de filhas que referenciem o pai que está tentando excluir, pode usar algo como:

```
SELECT 1 FROM tbl_filha1 WHERE id_pai = <id do pai>;
```

[...]

```
SELECT 1 FROM tbl_filhaN WHERE id_pai = <id do pai>;
```

Perceba que você terá que fazer isso para as N tabelas filhas (pelo menos até achar um resultado) o que seria um pouco oneroso. Considerando isso, no seu lugar eu faria a rotina para exclusão da tabela pai e trataria o erro na aplicação caso o SGBD barrasse a exclusão, sem fazer verificação prévia de tabelas filhas.

Comment: A sua proposta de utilizar o Count() pode ser uma opção, mas você terá que trabalhar com todas as tabelas filhas, sendo oneroso também.

Comment: Sim, não deixa de ser uma opção porém eu terei que disponibilizar o botão de "Excluir" para todos os registros na aplicação. O que seria perfeito é não exibir o botão para registros que não podem ser excluídos. Como a aplicação é web, eu já trato o erro do SGBD ao tentar excluir pois no meio tempo entre exibir os dados na aplicação e o usuário clicar em excluir, outro usuário online pode ter gerado dependência para o registro.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta o seguinte:

```
SELECT s.*, 

CASE WHEN 
    t.id_sistema IS NOT NULL OR
    c.id_sistema IS NOT NULL OR
    cs.id_sistema IS NOT NULL 
    THEN 'disabled'

END as desabilitar 

FROM sistema s
    LEFT JOIN telemetria t ON s.id = t.id_sistema
    LEFT JOIN controle c ON s.id = c.id_sistema
    LEFT JOIN cliente_sistema cs ON s.id = cs.id_sistema
```

O código acima vai listar todos os seus sistemas fazendo um left join com as demais tabelas. Isso vai fazer com que seja listado todos os sistemas independente se existe id_sistema nas outras tabelas.

O CASE WHEN está verificando se id_sistema nas outras tabelas está diferente de nulo. Se não estiver nulo, ele cria a coluna desabilitar = 'disabled'.

Agora no seu HTML, na listagem de sistema, utilize o campo desabilitar para atribuir o disabled ao botão.

```
<button <?= $rs['desabilitar'] ?>>DELETAR</button>
```

Se estiver utilizando tag de link, mude o valor da coluna desabilitar para 'none', e ai vc esconde o link com um css inline:

```
<a style="display:<?=$rs['desabilitar']?>">
```

Isso para poder evitar o `IF`. Mas você pode retornar `true` e fazer um if verificando se desabilitar = true, esconde o botão.

Porém como você disse que são milhões de registros, talvez a melhor opção seja tratar a exceção do banco quando você tentar excluir.

Porém vale tentar essa solução =)

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Cara, obrigado pelo esforço e pela contribuição. O raciocínio está correto mas os join deram problema de performance. A query levou 210 segundos em um Linux com i7 e 8GB de ram =) Mas valeu pelo esforço. Abraços!

Comment: A solução do Guilherme ficou realmente muito boa, e pelo que você comentou, bem rápida tbm. Maravilha!

Answer (score 0):

Eu faria tudo em uma só tabela, utilizando um campo chamado *filhode* com uma chave estrangeira para o id da própria tabela. Uso isso até para fazer menus. Veja um exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE menu
(
  idmenu serial NOT NULL,
  menu character varying(50),
  filhode integer,
  CONSTRAINT pk_idmenu PRIMARY KEY (idmenu),
  CONSTRAINT fk_filhode FOREIGN KEY (filhode)
      REFERENCES menu(idmenu) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
)
```

Com isso não preciso deste monte tabelas filhas como tbl_filha1, tbl_filha2 ... tbl_filha**x**. Tudo acontece em uma única tabela.